# Entity Framework 5 wrong data type in query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

We are using EF 5.0 as our ORM of choice in our business solution, structured in a n-layer fashion with everything decoupled and a nice composition root with ninject.

Lately, we've been building a database that uses partitioning underneath, and we have some important indexes on `DATE` columns.

The columns are correctly declared on Sql Server 2008. We also added the correct data type in the EF mappings, with the `HasColumnType("Date")` instruction.

Still, when querying the table through Linq to Entities, the parameters that we filter the dates on are created of type `DateTime2` and even the columns are cast to `DateTime2` in the queries so the type matches the parameters.

This behaviour has several problems. First of all, if I'm telling EF engine that the column on the database is `DATE` why should it cast it to `DateTime2`?

Second, this cast is making the database ignore the indexes, thus not using partitioning. We have one year per phisical partitioning, and if I ask a date range, let's say, february 2013 to march 2013 the scan should happend only on one physical partition. It works correctly if manually using the correct data type `DATE` but with the cast to `DateTime2` all the partitions get scanned, reducing performance drastically.

Now, I'm sure I'm missing out something, because it would be rather stupid that Microsoft ORM doesn't work well on Microsoft Sql Server.

I've been unable to find any documentation on how have EF use the correct data types in queries, so I'm asking here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that this is possible in Entity Framework.  [This requested enhancement](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2639292-support-for-simple-type-mapping-or-mapped-type-con) would probably do what you need.  [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344.aspx) shows the mapping between SQL Server types and CLR types.  Note that `date` is supported and is mapped to `DateTime`, but since several SQL types map to the same CLR type, EF is evidently picking one SQL type as the *preferred* eqivalent of the CLR type.

Could you wrap your selection code in a stored procedure?  If so, this would seem to be a reasonable solution.  You could use [DbSet{T}.SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696332%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to materialize objects from executing the sp.

## Code sample

The following short console application demonstrates the concept.  Note how the related entities are successfully lazy-loaded.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [Table("MyEntity")]    
    public class MyEntity
    {
        private Collection<MyRelatedEntity> relatedEntities;

        [Key]
        public virtual int MyEntityId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public virtual DateTime MyDate { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("MyEntity")]
        public virtual ICollection<MyRelatedEntity> RelatedEntities
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.relatedEntities == null)
                {
                    this.relatedEntities = new Collection<MyRelatedEntity>();
                }

                return this.relatedEntities;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Date: {0}; Related: {1}", this.MyDate, string.Join(", ", this.RelatedEntities.Select(q => q.SomeString).ToArray()));
        }
    }

    public class MyRelatedEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int MyRelatedEntityId { get; set; }

        public virtual int MyEntityId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MyEntityId")]
        public virtual MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }

        public virtual string SomeString { get;set;}
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities
        {
            get { return this.Set<MyEntity>(); }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        const string SqlQuery = @"DECLARE @date date; SET @date = @dateIn; SELECT * FROM MyEntity WHERE MyDate > @date";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());

            using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
            {
                context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity
                    {
                        MyDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2),
                        RelatedEntities =
                        {
                            new MyRelatedEntity { SomeString = "Fish" },
                            new MyRelatedEntity { SomeString = "Haddock" }
                        }
                    });

                context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity
                {
                    MyDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),
                    RelatedEntities =
                        {
                            new MyRelatedEntity { SomeString = "Sheep" },
                            new MyRelatedEntity { SomeString = "Cow" }
                        }
                });

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
            {
                IEnumerable<MyEntity> matches = context.MyEntities.SqlQuery(
                    SqlQuery,
                    new SqlParameter("@dateIn", DateTime.Today)).ToList();

                // The implicit ToString method call here invokes lazy-loading of the related entities.
                Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}; First: {1}.", matches.Count(), matches.First().ToString());
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using lazy loading on a ton of navigation properties. I would need to eager load everything and manually create my object graph, which is very complex and deep, so that's not an option. Maybe moving to a different ORM like NHibernate will be the right choice.

Comment: @MatteoMosca - I don't think that's actually the case, unless I've misunderstood the problem.  EF allows you to materialize the results of an sp as *attached* entities ("tracked by the context" according to MSDN), so lazy loading should work.  What you can't do is support *eager* loading using this method.

Comment: That might be interesting. I think that I missed on this feature. I'll take a look into it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The range of DateTime type in .NET and SQL server is different.

.NET DateTime range is : 0000-Jan-01 to 9999-Dec-31
SQL DateTime range is:  1900-Jan-01, 2079-Jun-06

To match the range, EF convert your .NET DateTime to SQL server DateTime2 type which has same range as .NET DateTime range.

I think your issue only happens when you have date property that is not assigned and passed to SQL server via EF. When the date is not assigned with specific value, it is default to DateTime.Min which is 0000-Jan-01 and that is causing the conversion to DateTime2.

I think you can either make your DateTime property nullable --> DateTime? or write a helper to convert your DateTime.Min to meet SQL DateTime range.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Actually, it's not. One example of our problem is related to a search using two dates as search range. The columns on the db are DATE not DateTime or DateTime2. I send to EF two valid .net DateTime values, perfectly in range (for instance, march 1 2013 and may 1 21013) and the conversion still happens.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution. I've never seen a LINQ-to-Entites query with .NET `DateTime` parameters involved that had used a parameter type in the SQL query other than `datetime2(7)`. I doubt that you can get rid of that. Just a try to explain why it is as it is:

Suppose you have an entity with a property `SomeNumber` of type `int`. What result would you expect for a query like this:

```
....Where(e => e.SomeNumber >= 7.3)....
```

Probably all entities where `SomeNumber` is `8` or greater. If the (floating point decimal) parameter `7.3` would be cast to the type `int` stored in the database you had to decide how to round `7.3` - to `7` (will lead to wrong result) or to `8`? OK, you could say, because my query says `>=` and I know the type in the DB is a whole number, rounding to `8` must be correct. If I would use `<=`, then rounding to `7` must be correct. If I would use `==`, oh... I must not round at all or I know that the result must be empty and I could directly translate this `Where` clause to `false`. And `!=` to `true`. But a parameter of `7.0` is a special case. Etc....

Well, the dilemma in this example has an easy solution: Decide on client side what you want by using an `int` parameter (`7` or `8`) in the first place.

The solution with `DateTime` is not so simple because .NET does not have a `Date` type. Queries with `DateTime` parameters will always have the form...

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2013, 5, 13, 10, 30, 0);
....Where(e => e.SomeDateTime >= dateTime)....
```

...and if `SomeDateTime` is stored as `date` in SQL Server you have again the rounding dilemma. Do I have to cast to `2013.05.13` or `2013.05.14`? For the query above the client would surely expect all entities with a date of 14th and later.

Well, you could do it smart, like: if the time portion of my `DateTime` parameter is midnight, cast to the date portion. If I use `>=` cast to the next day, etc., etc.... Or you could always cast to `datetime2(7)`. Then the result of the query is always correct and as the (.NET) client expects it. Correct... but perhaps with suboptimal index usage.

Comment: I'm not understanding why your first example should be a problem. SQL Server already allows filtering an integer column using a non integer value. Consider this script: https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/5574037 I can filter `MyColumn` using a float, and SQL Server does not cast the column to a float to do it: https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/5574040 so why it's screwing it up when Entity Framework is involved?

Comment: Your explanation is clear, but still I think something is missing. If SQL has a Date type, EF could just ignore the time portion of the .Net DateTime object. It even has a .Date property that returns a DateTime with midnight time. Are you maybe suggesting that we should use in our database only types that are .Net compliant? That seems quite a limitation.

Comment: This is a more fitting example: https://gist.github.com/kappa7194/5574997 Here SQL Server performs a `Clustered Index Seek` searching for values `GT` the `DATETIME` I specified, I think Entity Framework should simply pass the values to the underlying database (if it supports them) and let it do its things.

Comment: @MatteoMosca: I agree that there are possibly solutions. I'm not convinced myself from my examples. The way how SQL is generated and why it is generated this way is an advanced topic. Maybe you could try to report this as possible bug or request for improvement on CodePlex: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced  Albireo has good examples provided too.

Comment: @Albireo: These are good examples and your analysis is better founded than mine and well worth your own answer here.